# How to extract XML clob to rows Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to extract documentation element from following XML using SQL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definition>
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_Documentation">
   doc1
  </bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_2_Documentation">
   doc2
  </bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_3_Documentation">
   doc3
  </bpmn:documentation>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

I tried with:

```
SELECT
   XMLTYPE(t.diag).EXTRACT('/bpmn:definition/bpmn:documentation/text()').getStringVal()
FROM
   table_name t;
```

But I got:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '/bpmn:definition/bpmn:documentation/text()'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear for several reasons: 1) this is not valid xml.  Your opening and closing elements are not the same, 2) there is no namespace prefix definition, 3) you want to extract the element text, such as "doc1" or the id attribute?  4).  Extract (select) is separate from inserting into a table.  Please edit the question and make all the appropriate corrections so we can help properly.  thanks

Comment: I want to select the XML from the CLOB, I added sample XML maybe it is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean `select XMLTYPE(your_clob) from... `?

Comment: Yes I do, I want to select doc1, doc2, doc3 from XML

Comment: I added query I tried and error I got

Comment: The element beginning `<bpmn:definition>` ends with the wrong tag `</bpmn:definitions>`. At least fix that for us

Answer (score 1):

Your XML example is still incorrect, but here is a corrected, working example with the namespace fixed.  Change as needed:

```
with table_name as ( select '
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://test.com">
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_Documentation">
   doc1
  </bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_2_Documentation">
   doc2
  </bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:documentation id="Task_3_Documentation">
   doc3
  </bpmn:documentation>
</bpmn:definitions>' test_data from dual )
SELECT b.doc
from table_name t,
       XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://test.com' as "bpmn"),
       '/bpmn:definitions/bpmn:documentation' PASSING xmltype(t.test_data)
                       COLUMNS doc VARCHAR2(30) PATH './text()') b
```